# Intentando abrir urls en loop desde archivo .CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, bucles

Hola estoy aprendiendo Python, y he estado teniendo problemas para lograr abrir links desde un archivo csv, realizar una tarea y luego abrir el siguiente link y realizar nuevamente la misma tarea que en el primero.

```
A = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('disable-infobars');
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications');
options.add_argument('--start-maximized');
options.add_argument('--test-type');
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.reddit.com');
def loop_linksA():
    with open('URL1.csv', 'r') as f:
        r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter =';')
        for i, line in enumerate(r):
            if i == (A[0]+ '1'):
                driver.get(line['link'])
                time.sleep(5)
loop_linksA()
```

Lo que quiero lograr, es que cada vez que se ejecute la función `loop_linksA` se lea  la próxima URL en el archivo CSV. Es decir la siguiente URL a la que se leyó cuando se ejecutó por primera vez la función `loop_linksA`.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en **español**, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Traduce tu pregunta si quieres que sea respondida y no sea cerrada

Comment: Hola Juan, "teniendo problemas"  es demasiado genérico, ¿Cúal es el  problema en concreto que tienes?¿Es con selenium o con la lectura del csv? Si tienes problemas con el csv considera agregar algunas lineas del mismo a la pregunta (incluido el encabezado) para poder reproducir el problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola gracias FjSevilla! A ver si me puedo explicar: Lo que quiero lograr, es que cada vez que se ejecute la función "loop_linksA" se lea la proxima URL en el archivo CSV. Es decir la siguiente URL a la que se leyo cuando se ejecutó por primera vez la funcion "loop_linksA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo tu idea original, podrías usar una variable global `int` que almacene el índice de la última linea leída. Sin embargo, el comportamiento que deseas es justamente lo que un generador te puede ofrecer:

```
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver



def links_gen(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter =';')
        for line in r:
            yield line['link']

def get_link(links):
    try:
        link = next(links)
    except StopIteration:
        print("No hay más links disponibles")
        return 
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(5)


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--test-type')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.reddit.com')

links = links_gen('URL1.csv') # generador
get_link(links) # linea 1
get_link(links) # linea 2
get_link(links) # linea 3
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, estoy intentando hacerlo correr, pero sigo recibiendo el mismo error que antes                                                             
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}

Comment: Imprime el link que te llega del csv antes del `driver.get`, puede que sea una url inválida, por ejemplo por la presencia de caracteres de fin de linea que no deberían estar.

Comment: Solucionado! De tanto probar distintas cosas, habia modificado el archivo CSV. Por eso daba error. Muchisimas gracias por ayudar! Estoy empezando con python y me esta gustando bastante. Saludos